# Simple form validation script

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

This is a simple form validation script.

I'd like to:

- improve the jQuery validation
- simplify the jQuery code

Questions:

1. Should I be exporting pure JS validation to avoid potential conflicts with other libraries that users might have installed?
2. Is it worth the effort or should I stick with my jQuery code?
3. Is there a way to reduce the chances for conflict with the jQuery code without having to reworking it to JS?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$(document).ready(function() {

// when submit button is pressed
$("#form_name").submit(function() {

    var pass = true;

    var errors = {
        required    : 'this field is required',
        email       : 'enter a valid email address',
        numeric     : 'enter a number without spaces, dots or commas',
        alpha       : 'this field accepts only letters &amp; spaces'
    };

    var tests = {
        email       : /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/,
        numeric     : /^[0-9]+$/,
        alpha       : /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/
    };

    // clear error messages
    $(".error").removeClass();
    $(".error-message").remove();

    function displayError(el, type) {
        $(el).parent().addClass("error").find('label').append('<span class=\"error-message\"> &#8211; ' + errors[type] + '</span>');
    }

    $('.required, .email, .numeric, .alpha').each(function(){
        var value       = $(this).val();
        var valueExists = value.length === 0 ? false : true;

        var required    = $(this).hasClass('required');
        var email       = $(this).hasClass('email');
        var numeric     = $(this).hasClass('numeric');
        var alpha       = $(this).hasClass('alpha');

        if (required && value.length===0) {
            displayError(this,'required');
            pass=false;
        }

        else if (email && valueExists && !tests.email.test(value)) {
            displayError(this,'email');
            pass=false;
        }

        else if (numeric && valueExists && !tests.numeric.test(value)) {
            displayError(this,'numeric');
            pass=false;
        }

        else if (alpha && valueExists && !tests.alpha.test(value)) {
            displayError(this,'alpha');
            pass=false;
        }
    });

    return pass;
});
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: You need a cross browser solution. jQuery is one of them.

Comment: The thing that worries me is what happens when suddenly someone uses this on a site that also uses three other JS frameworks. Also, what happens when someone is already using another version of jquery and pastes this in.

Comment: This should be asked on stackoverflow as its a "how do I" question, not a code review.

Comment: @Justin808 Since the code is working in working condition, I figured code review would be better suited.

Comment: +1 @Justin. The question actually has several points: the one about conflicts belongs in Stackoverflow; the one about improving the JQuery code belongs here. This is one good example why, if one has several questions, it's better to separate them into different threads.

Comment: Is there a way to shift it to StackOverflow without duplicating it?

Comment: I have the power to shift the question to StackOverflow, but I'm not sure thats the correct thing to do. The question seems to mostly be about improving the existing code which belongs here. Ideally, the part about how to avoid conflict should have been asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: You are defining a function (displayError) inside of an event (#form_name.submit()). I would factor that out in any case. I would also feel compelled to remove a function which just duplicates jQuery functionality.

Comment: Are you really serving the document as XML? Otherwise the `CDATA` section makes no sense (HTML doesn’t recognise it) – and MSIE doesn’t render XML so I doubt it. For that reason, it’s generally a good idea to have JavaScript in external files, since you technically would need to escape `&` and `<` as entities otherwise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid conflict with any other libraries, wrap your code using the jQuery function, and additionally call jQuery.noConflict();

The only conflict you may have is if somebody else imported an object named jQuery into the global namespace.

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Example:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 //This is a jQuery function
 $('.myClass');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To protect from conflicting libraries wrap your code in an [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // ...
    });
} (jQuery.noConflict()));
```